# Convergence in probability for $\frac { \overline { X } (1-\overline { X } ) }{ \sqrt { n } -{ 1 }/{ \sqrt { n } } }$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, statistical-inference

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n \overset {\text{iid}}\sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p),$ and let $\overline { X } $ be the sample mean.

So I want to show how $\frac {\overline{X} (1-\overline{X})}{ \sqrt{n} - 1/{\sqrt n}}$ converges to zero.

> $\frac { \overline { X } (1-\overline{X}) }{ \sqrt{n} - 1/{\sqrt n}} \overset{P}{\longrightarrow} 0$

Any hint?

Comment: No need for probability here, since $X_i \in [0,1]$ for all $i$ implies $\overline{X} \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the bound for non-negative random variable $X$ and $\epsilon>0$ that
$$
P(X\geq \epsilon)\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}E[X].
$$
Here definitely we have $\frac{\bar{X}(1-\bar{X})}{\sqrt{n}-1/\sqrt{n}}\geq 0$, so
$$
P(\frac{\bar{X}(1-\bar{X})}{\sqrt{n}-1/\sqrt{n}}\geq \epsilon)\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}E[\frac{\bar{X}(1-\bar{X})}{\sqrt{n}-1/\sqrt{n}}] \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{p}{\sqrt{n}-1/\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow 0,
$$ 
as $n\rightarrow \infty$. The last inequality holds because $E\bar{X}(1-\bar{X})\leq E\bar{X}$. This implies $\frac{\bar{X}(1-\bar{X})}{\sqrt{n}-1/\sqrt{n}}\overset{P}{\rightarrow }0$.